# How to use instance ids from the ec2 module into another resource in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create multiple ec2-instances using the terraform registry module,
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance

Here is my code looks like,

**

- main.tf

**

```
locals {
  name   = "my-app-server"
  multiple_instances = var.multiple_instances_params
}
module "ec2_multiple" {
  source = "../../"

  for_each = local.multiple_instances

  name = "${local.name}-${each.key}"

  instance_type          = each.value.instance_type
  availability_zone      = each.value.availability_zone
  subnet_id              = each.value.subnet_id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.security_group.security_group_id]

  enable_volume_tags = false
  root_block_device  = lookup(each.value, "root_block_device", [])

  tags = local.tags
}
```

**

- terraform.tfvars

**

```
multiple_instances_params = {
    1 = {
      instance_type     = "t3.micro"
      availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
      subnet_id         = "subnet-xxxxxda3f7e"
      root_block_device = [
        {
          delete_on_termination  = false
          encrypted   = true
          kms_key_id  = "xxx"
          volume_type = "gp3"
          throughput  = 200
          volume_size = 100
          tags = {
            Name = "my-root-block"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    2 = {
      instance_type     = "t3.small"
      availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
      subnet_id         = "subnet-xxxxxa3f7e"
      root_block_device = [
        {
          delete_on_termination  = false
          encrypted   = true
          volume_type = "gp3"
          throughput  = 200
          volume_size = 100
          tags = {
            Name = "my-root-block"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
<<omitted for brevity>>
```

I need to add the following code into my main.tf but unable to figure out how to pass the instance_ids. The below code is not written by me but I need to add this into my code. I am not using **count** for creating multiple instances.

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "license-manager-ssm-association" {
  count            = var.instance_count
  name             = "AWS-GatherSoftwareInventory"
  association_name = "license-manager-ssm-association-forxxxxx"
  targets {
    key    = "InstanceIds"
    values = [aws_instance.app-server[count.index].id]
  }
}

resource "aws_licensemanager_license_configuration" "example_license_config" {
  name                  = "chkconfig-${var.Environment}"
  license_counting_type = "Instance"
}

resource "aws_licensemanager_association" "example" {
  count                     = var.instance_count
  license_configuration_arn = aws_licensemanager_license_configuration.example_license_config.arn
  resource_arn              = aws_instance.app-server[count.index].arn
}
```

Can someone please help me here? Is there a better way to add resources related to licence-manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is if the module you are invoking is providing the outputs you want. The second thing to consider is that you are creating multiple instances of module using `for_each`, which means the modules will use key/value pairs for references. If you do have the outputs you want defined in the module, then you could try with this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "license-manager-ssm-association" {
  name             = "AWS-GatherSoftwareInventory"
  association_name = "license-manager-ssm-association-forxxxxx"
  targets {
    key    = "InstanceIds"
    values = values(module.ec2_multiple)[*].id
  }
}

resource "aws_licensemanager_association" "example" {
  for_each                  = local.multiple_instances
  license_configuration_arn = aws_licensemanager_license_configuration.example_license_config.arn
  resource_arn              = module.ec2_multiple[each.key].arn
}
```

The first one is using the built-in [`values` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values) to fetch all the outputs for all the key/value pairs which are named `id`:

```
values = values(module.ec2_multiple)[*].id
```

If the module output is named different to `id`, then just use that name.

The second resource is using `for_each` (because you created the module instances with `for_each`), and then it is fetching the ARN of a single instance:

```
resource_arn = module.ec2_multiple[each.key].arn
```

Finally, to understand all of this, read the terraform documentation about using the [modules with `for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances). Also, make sure to understand how to use [module outputs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/syntax#accessing-module-output-values).

Comment: Hello Marko, Thank you for response. Really appreciate it.
The invoked module does have output id and I was trying to use it but somehow I didn't tried making use of built-in function, VALUES. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, the module that I am invoking, does include the code for create resource iam_role & iam_instance_profile as well. Now like you mentioned above that if I am using for_each, then it is going run multiple instance of the invoked module which if I am creating 4 ec2-instances then it will also create 4 iam roles & 4 instance profiles.

But what if I don't want that? I need single role and instance profile to be created and attached to all the 4 EC2s.

Should I explore the count method instead of for_each? Or for_each with resource instead of module?

Comment: Please post a different question with the relevant code.

Comment: I posted this as a different question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680540/terraform-spinning-up-multiple-ec2-instances-using-for-each-doesnt-meet-my-req

Would like to know your thoughts on this.