# Terraform: Spinning up multiple EC2 instances using for_each doesn't meet my requirement. Should I explore count method? Or with for_each it can work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

For one of my app deployment, I am trying to create multiple ec2-instances using the terraform registry module, https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance

I am using **for_each** which means it will create multiple instances of the module invoked. I don't want other resources to be created multiple times.

Here is the code looks like,

```
**main.tf**
locals {
  name   = "my-app-server"
  multiple_instances = var.multiple_instances_params
}

module "ec2_multiple" {
  source = "../../"
  for_each = local.multiple_instances

  name = "${local.name}-${each.key}"
  ami_ssm_parameter      = var.ami_ssm_parameter
  instance_type          = each.value.instance_type
  availability_zone      = each.value.availability_zone
  subnet_id              = each.value.subnet_id
  private_ip             = each.value.private_ip
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.App-server-Security-Group.security_group_id]

  enable_volume_tags = false
  root_block_device  = lookup(each.value, "root_block_device", [])
  user_data          = var.app_server_user_data
  key_name           = var.app_server_keyName
  tags               = var.mandatory_tags

  iam_role_name               = "${local.name}-ec2-iam-role"
  iam_role_use_name_prefix    = false
  create_iam_instance_profile = true
  iam_role_description        = "xxxx"
  iam_role_permissions_boundary      = var.permissions_boundary
  iam_role_policies       = {
    "ALM_policy" = aws_iam_policy.ALM_policy.arn
    "CW_agent_Policy" = aws_iam_policy.Cloud_Watch_Agent_Server_Policy.arn
  }
}

**terraform.tfvars**
multiple_instances_params = {
    server-1 = {
      instance_type     = "t3.micro"
      availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
      subnet_id         = "subnet-xxxa3fxx"
      private_ip        = "10.xx.xx.xxx"
      root_block_device = [
        {
          delete_on_termination  = false
          encrypted   = true
          kms_key_id  = "xxx"
          volume_type = "gp3"
          throughput  = 200
          volume_size = 100
          tags = {
            Name = "my-root-block"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    server-2 = {
      instance_type     = "t3.small"
      availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
      subnet_id         = "subnet-xxx16daxxxe"
      private_ip        = "10.xx.xx.xxx"
      root_block_device = [
        {
          delete_on_termination  = false
          encrypted   = true
          kms_key_id  = "xxx"
          volume_type = "gp3"
          throughput  = 200
          volume_size = 100
          tags = {
            Name = "my-root-block"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
<<omitted for brevity>>
}
```

This creates multiple instance of IAM role and Instance profile as well, which I do not want.

Also I don't want to make any change in the invoked module. So want to know if there is something that I can implement in my **main.tf** to achieve this? I mean multiple ec2 instances but a single iam role/instance profile gets attached to all the ec2 instances.

Other way of doing this would be to write a custom module and use **count** meta-argument with resources.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `count` instead of `for_each` in the module will produce the exact same resources in AWS, you will just have a different way to reference those results after they are created. So switching to `count` will not solve your issue.

Your possible solutions are:

- Create the IAM role and Instance Profile outside of the module, and pass them into the module, instead of having the module create them for you.
- Don't use a module at all, and just create the resources directly in your Terraform code, so that you have more control over what gets created.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I would probably go for Option 2.